# Learning jQuery's tabs + CSS Flexbox. Can anyone help get this working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to jQuery and advanced CSS. I was wondering if anyone could take a look at my code and help me get this working. Basically, the gray box on the left is supposed to be fixed and follow you as the page scrolls(that works). Essentially, I want to have the tabs in that gray scroll bar, and have the content of the tabs be displayed in the orange-ish flexbox on the right. I understand that my issue stems from the separation of the `<ul>` and content divs in HTML, because that's how jQuery reads the tabs. That being said, can anyone help me achieve what I'm looking for. The code is fairly convoluted, so any advice is welcome. I want to learn, so don't hold back!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').tabs();
    $('.ui-tabs-active').removeClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0px;
}
#wrapper {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:flex;
    margin-left:300px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#scrollBar {
    background-color:gray;
    height:300px;
    width:280px;
    position:fixed;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
#box1 {
    background-color:#ffcc66;
    height:1000px;
    flex:1;
}
.tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
}
.contentDiv {
    width:100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.tabs a {
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.tabs li:focus {
    outline:none;
    color:orange;
}
.tabs a:hover, .tabs a:focus {
    color:blue;
}
.tabs a:focus, .tabs a:active {
    outline: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:orange;
}
.ui-tabs-active a {
    color:orange;
    overflow:visible;
}
.contentDiv {
    width:100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="scrollBar">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="coding">Coding</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="photo">Photography</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="info">About Me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="box1">
            <div id="coding" class="contentDiv">
                <div class="fillerText">
                    <p>this is my code</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="photography" class="contentDiv">
                <div class="fillerText">
                    <p>these are my pictures</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="info" class="contentDiv">
                <div class="fillerText">
                    <p>this is my info</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/yk55vufk/

Comment: Do you really wanna use `$(...).tabs();`? I think the better solution is make an appropriate code to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you have added this line :

```
 $('.ui-tabs-active').removeClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
```

In your code you don't have classes "**ui-tabs-active**", "**ui-tabs-active**", "**ui-state-active**"

some classes and jquery needs be fixed in your code :

Here is  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk55vufk/4/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Originally that line wad used to deselect everything when you first arrive at the page. Over time, I removed some classes and that bit became redundant. Thanks for pointing it out.